# Make .net framework libraries redistruable

Tags: c#, .net, libraries

i got an idea and i`d like to know if can it become true or not , now lets say i made a program using VS C# 2010 and i used the 2 libraries using system; and using system.IO;

can i take these 2 libraries from the .net frame work it self and include them into my application folder and import them into my application using references . so i don`t have to install the .net framework on the target machine , is this possible ? and if yes , where can i find the .net libraries to download and include .. thanks a lot for your help in advance .

Comment: Make sure you're not targeting a later framework than needed. Most people have some .net installed, but perhaps not 4.0. So if you're not using 4.0, don't target it

Comment: Let's say you can do that, how would you run it since the CLR ships with .Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that's not possible since you'll still need CLR which is integrated part of .NET Framework. If you want a .NET application to run without the Framework installed, use [VMware ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

No. Your users should install the .NET framework for your application. Here is a helpful site:

http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/

Answer (score 0):

No. Simply because .NET Framework runs on a software environment and to make that happen you need CLR (Common Language Runtime) on the client's computer. Along with this the .NET Framework comprises of various other base classes which are needed for the application to run!